# Icon next to axis range label amcharts

Tags: javascript, html, css, amcharts

how to position icon next to label on radar chart, because I can’t make this work. It’s and example from website [Example](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/radar-timeline/) but I am learning and I don’t know if I am missing something.:

https://codepen.io/buyyan-the-sans/pen/QWYNezN

```
function createRange(name, continentData, index) {
  const LETTER_SIZE = 16;
  var axisRange = categoryAxis.createAxisRange(categoryAxis.makeDataItem({above:true}));
  axisRange.get("label").setAll({ 
    text: name,
  });
  axisRange.set("bullet", am5xy.AxisBullet.new(root, {
      sprite: am5.Picture.new(root, {
      width: 15,
      height: 15,
      centerX: am5.percent(140),
      centerY: am5.percent(250),
      src: "https://i.imgur.com/MyrDBkI.png",
    })
  }))
  // first country
  axisRange.set("category", continentData[0][0]);
  // last country
  axisRange.set("endCategory", continentData[continentData.length - 1][0]);

  // every 3rd color for a bigger contrast
  var fill = axisRange.get("axisFill");
  fill.setAll({
    toggleKey: "active",
    cursorOverStyle: "pointer",
    fill: colorSet.getIndex(index * 3),
    visible: true,
    innerRadius: -25
  });
  axisRange.get("grid").set("visible", false);

  var label = axisRange.get("label");
  label.setAll({
    fill: am5.color(0xffffff),
    textType: "circular",
    radius: -16
  });

  fill.events.on("click", function(event) {
    var dataItem = event.target.dataItem;
    if (event.target.get("active")) {
      categoryAxis.zoom(0, 1);
    }
    else {
      categoryAxis.zoomToCategories(dataItem.get("category"), dataItem.get("endCategory"));
    }
  });
}
```

I tried Container, Bullet and they didn’t work